# TableView with its sticky header

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I'm new to iPhone. I am developing an app where i want to create something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJm7subFbQI&feature=youtu.be . 
I want to achieve this kind of effect.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You  need to add tableview with section.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableViewHeader (fix position)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490511/uitableviewheader-fix-position)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element you are looking for is a `UITableView`.

Got through Apple's [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html), to learn more about how to use `tableView`s.

In short, there are 2 parts to this: Cells, and Sections. You should be aware of `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` to achieve this.

The `UITableViewDataSource` defines methods to provide data for the cells and sections in the table, while the `UITableViewDelegate` defines behaviour of these cells and sections.

In the video you have posted, the part of the table that scrolls normally are the cells, while the part that stays at the top are the sections. You define the content of the cells and sections in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `viewForHeaderInSection:` methods, respectively.

Here is the another question [Customize UITableView header section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611374/customize-uitableview-header-section)
Here is the tutorial How to do so... follow the link and you will able to make the same effect.
http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customizing-headers-and-footers-of-a-tableview